# Requiring gem in Ruby on Rails - OilyPNG vs ChunkyPNG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, chunkypng

I am currently using [ChunkyPNG](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png), but I want to give [OilyPNG](https://github.com/wvanbergen/oily_png) a try.  I have tried using it in a simple ruby script and the performance is much better. I basically install both gems in the Gemfile and require 'oily_png' in my script.

However, in my RoR app, I fail to see how to `require 'oily_png'`. I am currently not requiring chunky_png anywhere, but in the docs is said that I need to `require 'oily_png'`. Where would I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just avoid requiring ChunkyPNG on the Gemfile.  Something like this:

```
gem 'chunky_png', :require => false
```

So, the **ChunkyPNG** gem will be installed, but when Rails tells **Bundler** to require all the gems, this one won't be required, but the **OilyPNG** will be.